# Tamaño de labels y valores en un barplot de ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hice cuatro barplots en ggplot: o, p, q, r. Los junté en un solo plot usando la librería ggpubr y el siguiente código:

```
library(ggpubr)

figure = ggarrange(o + font("y.text", size = 5), p + 
font("y.text", size = 5), q + font("y.text", size = 5), r + 
font("y.text", size = 5), labels = c("Total", "DF", "SE", "RU"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

annotate_figure(figure,top = text_grob("Distribución de víctimas por departamento según hecho victimizante", 
color = "black", face = "bold", size = 10))
```

Esto resultó: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema: tanto los labels como los valores de los extremos de las barras son muy grandes. Cómo puedo hacerlos más chicos sin tener que modificar los plots o, p, q, r)? Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primer parte de tu duda se resuelve agregando una función `font.label` te muestro un ejemplo muy sencillo utilizando el data set de mtcars

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(purrr)
p<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + geom_text(stat='count', 
   aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1) 
q<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + geom_text(stat='count', 
   aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
 o<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + geom_text(stat='count', 
   aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)  
 r<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + geom_text(stat='count', 
    aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)  

figure<-ggarrange(o,p,q,r + font("legend.text", size = 2),
                        labels = c("Total", "DF", "SE", "RU"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                         font.label=list(color="green",size=11))
```

con lo que se obtiene la primera parte de la pregunta es decir desde font.label puedes modificar el tamaño y color de los "labels"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda parte de la pregunta es mas complicada ya que tenemos que meternos a las entrañas de cada una de las graficas para modificar el tamaño del texto, para esto asumo que utilizo la función de ggplot para generarlas , por lo que utilizamos  `ggplot_build` para poder revisar cuales son los datos que componen a cada una de las graficas

```
$data
$data[[1]]
   y count    prop x flipped_aes PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
1 11    11 0.34375 4       FALSE     1    -1    0   11  3.1  4.9     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
2  7     7 0.21875 6       FALSE     1    -1    0    7  5.1  6.9     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
3 14    14 0.43750 8       FALSE     1    -1    0   14  7.1  8.9     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA

$data[[2]]
   y label count    prop x width flipped_aes PANEL group colour size angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight
1 11    11    11 0.34375 4   1.8       FALSE     1    -1  black 3.88     0   0.5    -1    NA               1        1.2
2  7     7     7 0.21875 6   1.8       FALSE     1    -1  black 3.88     0   0.5    -1    NA               1        1.2
3 14    14    14 0.43750 8   1.8       FALSE     1    -1  black 3.88     0   0.5    -1    NA               1        1.2


$layout
<ggproto object: Class Layout, gg>
    coord: <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg>
        aspect: function
        backtransform_range: function
        clip: on
        default: TRUE
        distance: function
        expand: TRUE
        is_free: function
        is_linear: function
        labels: function
        limits: list
        modify_scales: function
        range: function
        render_axis_h: function
        render_axis_v: function
        render_bg: function
        render_fg: function
        setup_data: function
        setup_layout: function
        setup_panel_guides: function
        setup_panel_params: function
        setup_params: function
        train_panel_guides: function
        transform: function
        super:  <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg>
    coord_params: list
    facet: <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg>
        compute_layout: function
        draw_back: function
        draw_front: function
        draw_labels: function
        draw_panels: function
        finish_data: function
        init_scales: function
        map_data: function
        params: list
        setup_data: function
        setup_params: function
        shrink: TRUE
        train_scales: function
        vars: function
        super:  <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg>
    facet_params: list
    finish_data: function
    get_scales: function
    layout: data.frame
    map_position: function
    panel_params: list
    panel_scales_x: list
    panel_scales_y: list
    render: function
    render_labels: function
    reset_scales: function
    setup: function
    setup_panel_guides: function
    setup_panel_params: function
    train_position: function
    xlabel: function
    ylabel: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class Layout, gg>

$plot

attr(,"class")
[1] "ggplot_built"
```

En este ejemplo en particular lo que queremos modificar el el tamaño de todas las graficas que aparecen en $data[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sXRK.png)] en la columna size una forma rapida de hacerlo es la siguiente para no realizarla una a una

```
lista<-list(o=o,p=p,q=q,r=r)

lista_limpia<-map(lista,function(x){ a<-ggplot_build(x); a$data[[2]]$size<-3;b<-as_ggplot(ggplot_gtable(a));b})
                    
figure<-ggarrange(lista_limpia$o,lista_limpia$p,lista_limpia$q,lista_limpia$r+ font("legend.text", size = 2),
                            labels = c("Total", "DF", "SE", "RU"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                             font.label=list(color="green",size=11))
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es guardando las graficas como listas paras despues con la función de map cambiar el tamaño de la letra de a 3 , creo que el metodo se vuelve un poco complicado y seria mas sencillo cambiarlo al momento de generar la grafica el resultado final es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias RUBEN. La primera parte funcionó. La segunda aún no. Al final del código que pusiste está: 
`][2]][2]` 
que arroja un error. Imagino que quisiste decir `[[2]][2]` 
Copié el código que propusiste, modificando esa parte final. Luego, en la consola puse: `figure`
Salió el siguiente mensaje: 

[[1]]
mapping: x = ~x, y = ~y, label = ~text 
geom_text: parse = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity 

No se desplegó ningún gráfico. Tampoco funcionó modificando tu código al final poniendo `[2][2]`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Con una ligera modificación, pero siguiendo tu lógica, ya pude obtener algo mucho más cercano a lo que buscaba. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: `lista<-list(o=o,p=p,q=q,r=r)`

`lista_limpia<-map(lista,function(x){ a<-ggplot_build(x); a$data[[2]]$size<-2;b<-as_ggplot(ggplot_gtable(a));b})`

`figure<-ggarrange(lista_limpia$o,lista_limpia$p,lista_limpia$q,lista_limpia$r + font("legend.text", size = 2), labels = c("Total", "DF", "SE", "RU"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2,font.label=list(color="black",size=9))`

`annotate_figure(figure,top = text_grob("Distribución de víctimas por departamento según hecho victimizante", color = "black", face = "bold", size = 10))`

Comment: Hola Ivan, tienes razón [2][2] no es parte del código(ya lo modifique ) lo que sucedió fue que se quedo esa parte al agregar la segunda  imagen (ya que tuve un problema agregándola), que bueno que la respuesta te allá ayudado Saludos